# UIStackView subviews animating only when isHidden is set to false

Tags: swift, animation, uistackview

I am trying to hide/show my subview of a `UIStackView` within an animation block like so:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
   self.unpairSensorButton.isHidden = isHidden
}
```

Showing animation works perfectly, but when I try to hide it, it just waits for the animation duration and then just immediately disappears. Any idea why?

I have tried to use the `layoutIfNeeded()` and putting it into  `DispatchQueue.main.async` block bot neither helped.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Did you expect it to fade out?

Comment: It is a vertical stack view, so I would expect it to appear in a reversed animation to the showing one. But instead it just suddenly disappears.

Comment: I still don't get what you want to happen. If you want it to fade in, set `alpha` to 1. If you want it to fade out, set `alpha` to 0. `isHidden` is not animatable.

Comment: Of course it is animatable. That's why it animates when I set isHidden to true.

Comment: So it _works_? What's wrong with your code then?

Comment: You probably didn't understand what I want here. The animation of showing is working, but the animation of hiding doesn't. If you look inside the documentation of UIStackView there is an example of how it can be done, but that's apparently not working for some reason.

Comment: please share the complete code of your view/controller. the problem lays somewhere else because code above works fine in a clean project

Comment: The `isHidden` flag is not animatable, but the `UIStackView` is observing changes to the property and animates stuff based on the property value.

Answer (score -1):

`isHidden` property is not animatable by itself.
`UIStackView` basically changes its internal constraints to adapt its size when you hide some subview. Since constraints are animatable, you would do this:

```
unpairSensorButton.isHidden = isHidden
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Calling `layoutIfNeeded()` in an animation block will animate the layout process.

Comment: this is basically incorrect since UIStackView observers view and applies animation
https://monosnap.com/file/UyMyLFJESMYLf0Tn8PLjJLGw3X760n